# How to remove Firestore documents from an array if they already exists in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to remove duplicate documents in an array of type `addShops` which is a custom object I created to add my documents and view them in a tableView later on.

I want to know how can I check if a Firestore document already exists in the array?

I am intermediate in swift and iOS development so I still don't know anything advanced in terms of arrays and Firebase Firestore.

So, I would appreciate any help.

Here is my code:

```
addShop:
protocol DocumentSerializable {
    init?(dictionary:[String:Any])
}

struct addShop {
    
    var shopPID:String
    var name:String
    var location:String
    var numTables:String
    var traffic:String
    var indoor:Bool
    var outdoor:Bool
    var drivethru:Bool
    var takeaway:Bool
    //images URL
    var shopProfileImage:String
    var shopHeaderImage:String
    //true or false
    var sponsered:Bool
    //Numbers
    var ratings:Float
    var contactNumber:String
    
    
    var dictionary:[String:Any]
    {
        return [
            "shopPID":shopPID,
            "name":name,
            "location":location,
            "numTables":numTables,
            "traffic":traffic,
            "indoor":indoor,
            "outdoor":outdoor,
            "drivethru":drivethru,
            "takeaway":takeaway,
            "ShopProfileImg":shopProfileImage,
            "ShopHeaderImg":shopHeaderImage,
            "sponsered":sponsered,
            "ratings":ratings,
            "contactNumber":contactNumber
        ]
    }
    
}

extension addShop : DocumentSerializable {
    
    init?(dictionary:[String:Any]) {
        
        guard let shopPID = dictionary["shopPID"] as? String,
            let name = dictionary["name"] as? String,
            let location = dictionary["location"] as? String,
            let numTables = dictionary["numTables"] as? String,
            let traffic = dictionary["traffic"] as? String,
            let indoor = dictionary["indoor"] as? Bool,
            let outdoor = dictionary["outdoor"] as? Bool,
            let drivethru = dictionary["drivethru"] as? Bool,
            let takeaway = dictionary["takeaway"] as? Bool,
            let shopProfileImage = dictionary["ShopProfileImg"] as? String,
            let shopHeaderImage = dictionary["ShopHeaderImg"] as? String,
            let sponsered = dictionary["sponsered"] as? Bool,
            let ratings = dictionary["ratings"] as? Float,
            let contactNumber = dictionary["contactNumber"] as? String
            else {return nil}
        self.init(shopPID: shopPID, name: name, location: location, numTables: numTables,traffic: traffic,indoor:indoor,outdoor:outdoor,drivethru:drivethru,takeaway:takeaway ,shopProfileImage: shopProfileImage,shopHeaderImage: shopHeaderImage,sponsered: sponsered, ratings: ratings,contactNumber:contactNumber)
    }
}
```

Firestore code where i want to check documents in the array:

```
  func getNextShops() {
    
        if self.lastDoc != self.firestoreLastDocument{
      
            db.collection("Shops").order(by: "__name__").start(afterDocument: lastDoc!).limit(to: 8).getDocuments(){ docs, err in
                self.docsCount = docs?.count
                if  self.docsCount == 0{
                    self.tableView.stopLoading()
                    return
                }else{
                if let err = err {
                    print(err.localizedDescription)
                }else{
                        docs?.documents.forEach{ data in
                            
                            //here i want to check if the document already exists,
                            //if it exists do not append it again to the array.
                           
                                self.shops.append(addShop(dictionary: data.data())!)
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                                    
                                }
                        }
                    self.lastDoc = docs?.documents[(docs?.documents.endIndex)! - 1]
                    self.lastDocID = self.lastDoc?.documentID
            
                    }
                }
            }
            } else {
                
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the main question (how do you tell if the document exists), it probably depends what your qualification for "exists" is.

For example, if you mean "does the array already have an element with the same `shopPID`, you could do this:

```
guard let shopPID = document.get("shopPID") as? String,
    !self.shops.contains { $0.shopPID == shopPID }
  else {
       return
}
```

If you want to check for complete equality, you'd need to make sure that your model conforms `Equatable` and then you could do:

```
guard let newShop = addShop(dictionary: data.data()) else {
  return
}
if !self.shops.contains(newShop) {
  //add it to the array
}
```

---

There are a couple of other things that you might want to consider cleaning up in your code:

1. In Swift, types generally start with capital letters. At the least, `addShop` should probably be `AddShop`. And, really, it should probably just be `Shop`
2. You're doing a lot of extra work by converting to/from a `[String:Any]` by hand. And, it leads to potential typos/inconsistencies/errors (for example, why does every property in your model use a lowercase letter except for `ShopProfileImg` and `ShopHeaderImg`? I'd do some reading on `Codable` and then check out this section of the Firebase documentation on using custom objects: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#custom_objects

Here's a pretty extensive article about Codable and Firestore: https://peterfriese.dev/firestore-codable-the-comprehensive-guide/

3. Beware of using `!` to force unwrap -- this will crash your app if it fails

Comment: With its current name, you would start the declaration of the type by doing `struct addShop : Equatable {`

Comment: wow amazing answer. i've been working on this problem for more than a week now for atleast 4 hours a day and didnt find a solution. today i thought about this array methodology to check first if a document exists or not but i didn't know how to implement it. Thank you sir, your code will help me improve more and more in iOS development. much appreciated!!!!!